# Lumen sounds like query does not return when like queries do return

Tags: laravel, eloquent, lumen

Hi i have 2 question regarding queries in Lumen.

Question 1 is as follows:

I have this Product Eloquent model:

```
class Product extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, AuthorizableContract {

    use Authenticatable, Authorizable;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'description', 'company', 'image', 'url', 'category_id', 'created_at'
    ];
}
```

Now when I perform this query I get results:

```
Product::query()
            ->where('name', 'sounds like', "%{$search}%")
            ->orWhere('description', 'like', "%{$search}%")
            ->get();
```

However when I perform this I do not get results:

```
Product::where('name', 'sounds like', $search)->get()
```

Question 2 is similar in that how do I do these queries with a limit and offset? as when I add ->slice I get the following:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::slice()

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

Comment: What about the syntax like I have? with Product::where(...)...?

Comment: "Since Eloquent models are query builders, you should review all of the methods available on the query builder. You may use any of these methods in your Eloquent queries." [Laravel 6.x Docs - Eloquent - Retrieving Models](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#retrieving-models)    :-)   ... all of that applies to Eloquent queries, which is what you are building ... `Model::where(...)->...->take(...)->skip(...)->get();` and the likes